# How to package VC++ Redistributables (for VS 2013) into a cab file?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex

How to package VC++ Redistributable runtime library (for Visual Studio 2013 available [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe)) into a cab file that should get downloaded automatically only if needed on the client machine?

The sample packaging given at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't help as they have not made mfc120.cab available at the similar url, the way they did for mfc42 as in their sample.

As a workaround (which works) I have created a cab (vcredist_x86.cab) out of the vcredist_x86.exe and invoking it only if any of the dependent runtime libraries are not available. But I believe there could be a direct way of doing things instead of going this odd way.

Here is the inf (inspired by the msdn sample):

```
[version]
    signature="$CHICAGO$"
    AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
myModule.ocx=myModule.ocx
mfc120u.dll=mfc120u.dll
msvcr120.dll=msvcr120.dll
msvcp120.dll=msvcp120.dll

[myModule.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={C4B5FFD0-6DE6-D47E-A9B1-5CF1D3EE869C}
FileVersion=1.5.0.12
RegisterServer=yes

[mfc120u.dll]
    FileVersion=12,00,21005,1
    hook=mfc120installer

[msvcr120.dll]
    FileVersion=12,00,21005,1
    hook=mfc120installer

[msvcp120.dll]
    FileVersion=12,00,21005,1
    hook=mfc120installer

[mfc120installer]
    file-win32-x86=vcredist_x86.cab
    run=%EXTRACT_DIR%\vcredist_x86.exe \Q
```

It would be great to know the right way of packaging this particular version of VS 2013 - similar to the sample given. I don't want to copy the vcredist_x86.exe or the dlls at the server, so that it works fine as given in the msdn sample.

Comment: They are just simple plain DLLs, just copy them.  And consider building your module with /MT so you don't need them at all.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but this way seems odd compared to the sample given by msdn. Hence the question, otherwise the workaround mentioned seems to be the **only** option - correct?